# What technologies have the developers of reverbnation achieved their across site player?

Tags: jquery, ajax, audio, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I have been trying to figure out how the developers of reverbnation have achieved their player which will stay playing seamlessly while the user browses. It doesn't look like either full site ajax or frames to me, but maybe I'm mistaken.

I have a client who wants me to price an across site player so I would appreciate any elaboration.

http://www.reverbnation.com/

( click a song to play and then browse the site - song stays playing, no glitches )

EDIT or if anyone has any better suggestions, as long as they don't involve glitches.

The playback will be user initiated.

Comment: What's the close vote for please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](http://netmix.com/making-your-audio-player-persistent-with-jquery-and-ajax/2013/01/13/5557/) which identify the technologies and provide some links. Reverbnation does seem to be ajax even though it didn't look like it to me the fact that it employs deep linking/history.js/hijax means it looks quite like a regular non ajax site. I don't fully understand how these techniques/technologies overlap or interact with one another but this is the general area anyway - more on [this page](http://jsallthethings.com/2012/deeplinking-and-indexing-ajax-applications-google-hashbang-and-state-maintenance)